# Is this a prime Ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I wish to see wether $J=(uw -v^2, u^3 - vw, w^3 -u^5)\subset\mathbb{C}[u,v,w]$ is a prime ideal. Can somebody give me a hint to do this?

**Edit:** More generally, I wonder wether $V(J)$, the algebraic set given by the vanishing locus of $J$, is irreducible.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to state what you actually intend to prove. Namely, that the vanishing locus of that ideal is a variety.

Comment: I did want to prove irreducibility but I also wanted to see wether $J$ is a prime ideal or not. That's why I wrote my question this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question has been tagged algebraic geometry, I should say a little bit about how we determine if the vanishing locus of your ideal is a variety. Now  a first step of course would be to attempt to show that $I$ is prime. If this were the case, the Nullstellensatz then gives that $\mathcal{I}\mathcal{V}(I) = \operatorname{rad} I = I$  so that $\mathcal{V}(I)$ is a variety. However it may be the case that $I$ is not prime, so there is an alternative way as follows.

In your case we wish to determine if $$V = \mathcal{V}(uw - v^2, u^3 - vw, w^3 - u^5)$$

is a variety. Then any point $(x,y,z) \in V$ necessarily satisfies

$$xz = y^2,\hspace{2mm} x^3 = yz,\hspace{2mm} z^3 = x^5.$$

We may suppose that $(x,y,z) \neq 0$ (for the origin is already in $V$) to get that $x^4 = y^3, z^3 = x^5$ and so

$$x = \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^3,\hspace{2mm} y = \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^4, \hspace{2mm} z = \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^5. $$

This means to say that $V$ is actually the image of the polynomial map

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \varphi : &\Bbb{A}^1& \longrightarrow V \\
&t& \mapsto (t^3,t^4,t^5). \end{eqnarray*}$$

Since $\Bbb{A}^1$ is a variety it follows that $V$ is a variety too. Notice how I don't need to invoke any Nullstellensatz to prove that $V$ was a variety this way!

**Edit:** To the person that downvoted my answer, why is it wrong? If you don't tell me what's wrong how am I supposed to improve?

Comment: This proves $V$ is irreducible. It does _not_ prove that $I$ is prime – only that $\operatorname{rad} I$ is prime.

Comment: @伟轩: Thank you and +1, since that was actually my original purpose!

Comment: @Heitor No problems mate! When I saw your question I made an *ansatz* that you were trying to show that the vanishing locus of that ideal was an affine variety.

Comment: Dear (complicated characters I can't reproduce),  you write " In your case, suppose we wish to determine if $V = \mathcal{V}(uw - v^2, u^3 - vw, w^3 - u^5)$
is affine". Of course it is affine:  $\mathcal{V}(\text{anything})$ is affine.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Dear Georges, I am following what Fulton means by an "affine variety" as an irreducible algebraic set. If this terminology is not standard, I will replace "affine" with irreducible.

Comment: Dear friend, the complication is in the word "variety", not the word "affine". "Variety" implies irreducibility.There are actually two possible problems here: showing that $J$ is prime or, less difficult *a priori*, showing that its radical $\sqrt J$ is prime (which suffices to ensure irreducibility of $V(J)$)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Dear Georges, first of all I should say that we have communicated with each other many times in the past, I am user BenjaLim (sorry for changing my profile name). Now I have edited my answer, is it better now? Furthermore doesn't my answer show that the vanishing locus of the OP's ideal is a variety?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Dear Georges, I have tried to edit my username but unfortunately math.se says that I can only do it after the $21^{\text{st}}$ of April. Sigh....
However you are welcome to ping me as `@Benja`.

Comment: Dear @Benja, yes  your calculation shows that $V(J)$ is a variety (in Fulton's sense) or equivalently that the radical $\sqrt J$  is prime. This is well done: +1. I would encourage you to at least add some Latin characters to your pseudonym, since my browser for example doesn't display anything sensible (I suppose I have some tuning to do). Also, more importantly, if one knows you, one might suspect that a misunderstanding arises from wrong terminology, whereas in this case I thought you had no idea of what you were talking about!

Comment: ...and I'l wait till April 21 to revive my friendship with @Benja  :-)

Comment: @伟轩 : Somebody downvoted my question as well. So I guess it was just someone who likes downvoting for its own sake, without seeking for any improvement.

Comment: @Heitor You already know that your ideal is not prime, and I have answered your original question that you had in mind. Would you like to accept one of the answers so that this question doesn't keep getting bumped up onto the main page? Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I have changed my username with someone's help :)

Answer (score 5):

$J$ is prime if and only if $\Bbb C[u,v,w]/J$ is an integral domain.
So, what does $\Bbb C[u,v,w]/J$ looks like ?

Since in the quotient, $w^3 = u^5$, $w$ should look like a $5$th power. 
This should lead you to define the map $\Bbb C[u,v,w] \to \Bbb C[x], P(u,v,w) \mapsto P(x^3,x^4,x^5)$.

Now, the tedious part is to prove that the kernel of this map is exactly $J$, so that this gives an isomorphism $\Bbb C[u,v,w]/J \to \Bbb C[x^3,x^4,x^5]$, which is obviously an integral domain.

Comment: @YACP: You are right. I instinctively accepted it as an answer because, as I wrote, I was only asking for a hint; however I have to change my mind: this answer provides me with a good hint I was looking for, but I have to leave open the possibility for a complete answer to be accepted.

Comment: Furthermore, after some calculations I found that the kernel is generated by $uw -v^2, u^3 - vw, u^2v-w^2$ and the last one is not clear why is in $J$.

Comment: @YACP : indeed, the kernel is not $J$, and thus $J$ is not prime : $(u^2v-w^2)u = (u^3-vw)v - (uw - v^2)w \in J$,but neither $u$ nor $u^2v-w^2$ are in $J$. Looks like it wasn't quite the right question.